# Clip OR Overlay in ArcGIS output feature empty

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, overlay

I use the Clip and Overlay to deal with download data. But they do not work and result in failure. Maybe the data is too large for ArcGIS Desktop to calculate. I do not know where I can check whether the data is OK for ArcGIS Desktop.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking that your datasets have the same coordinate system and draw in the same extent?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact version of ArcGIS and describe the origin, data type and feature count of your parameters. Complex polygons can often contain [topology errors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/checking-and-repairing-geometries.htm); have you tried using Check Geometry? It's also sometimes useful to [disable background geoprocessing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/foreground-and-background-processing.htm)

Comment: Neither of these background jobs have finished (one is unstarted). Does the process return an error, or are you just not waiting for completion?